# Identification in a non-linear simultaneous equation model

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics, identifiability, simultaneous-equation

I have the following model:

\begin{align*}
&\ln(cs_t)=c_1+c_2\ln(cs_{t-1})+c_3\ln(y_t)+c_4q1_t+c_5q2_t+c_6q3_t+u_{1t}\newline
&\ln(i_t)=c_7+c_8\ln(i_{t-1})+c_9\ln(b_t)+c_{10}(\ln(y_t)-\ln(y_{t-4}))+c_{11}q1_t+c_{12}q2_t+c_{13}q3_t+u_{2t}\newline
&\ln(xp_t)=c_{14}+c_{15}\ln(xp_{t-1})+c_{16}\ln(b_t)+c_{17}\ln(e_t)+c_{18}q1_t+c_{19}q2_t+c_{20}q3_t+u_{3t}\newline
&\ln(m_t)=c_{21}+c_{22}\ln(m_{t-1})+c_{23}\ln(e_t)+c_{24}\ln(y_t)+u_{4t}\newline
&\ln(e_t)-\ln(e_{t-4})=c_{25}+c_{26}\ln(b_t)+c_{27}(\ln(b_t)-\ln(b_{t-1}))+c_{28}(\ln(i_t)-\ln(i_{t-4}))+u_{5t}\newline
&tb_t=xp_t-m_t\newline
&y_t=cs_t+i_t+tb_i
\end{align*}
where $y_t, cs_t, i_t, tb_t, e_t$ are assumed to be endogenous; the other variables are treated as exogenous.

I need to show that this system is identified. My problem is, I don't understand how to apply the rank and order criteria when there are both linear and logarithmic functions of the variables. Specifically, I do not understand whether I need to treat the logarithms as distinct variables.

Do I treat $\ln(m_t)$ and $m_t$ as the same and apply the rank and the order criteria as with linear equations? If not, how do I proceed?

Comment: I don't understand this question, because "$e_t$" never appears as a variable in any of these equations.  If it helps, just change your notation and write, say "$d_t$" in place of every "$ln(e_t)$" that appears.  Use a similar change of notation for all other logarithms that appear.  This might be problematic for "$m_t,$" which appears both by itself and as a logarithm.  I'm unsure about "$b_i,$" which perhaps is a typographical error for "$b_t.$"  It's hard to know because you don't explain what these variables mean or what the model is intended to do. And is "$tb_t$" a variable or a product?

Comment: @whuber yes, I'm actually not sure what to do with the varables which appear as logarithms and as themselves. Do I treat the variable and its logarithm as two distinct variables?  $$tb_t$ is a variable.

Comment: If the logarithms are to be treated as distinct variables, then the SEM is over-identified, assuming the logarithms of the endogenous variables are endogenous variables.

Comment: Unless a variable is constant, it is not a linear multiple of its logarithm.  It would therefore be incorrect to treat the variable and its log as not being distinct in any model like this that is linear in its parameters.  But the notation is so obscure -- the ambiguous meaning of "$tb_t$" being just one example -- that I hesitate to say anything about this particular circumstance.

Comment: @whuber are you asking for an error term? Is it possible that $u_t$ expresses the errors?

Comment: @honkhonk can you reference what it means for a model to be "identified"?

Comment: @AdamO $u_t$ do represent the error terms for respective equations.

Comment: @AdamO I'm referring to identification in terms of the rank and order conditions as explained here: https://ebrary.net/1028/economics/identification.   A model is identifed (over-identified) if there is a way (or many ways) to estimate its coefficients, denoted here as $c_i,\quad i=\overline{1,28}$.

Comment: @Adam I am asking for clarification of an ambiguous and opaque notation.  But if the question really comes down to whether a variable $X$ and its logarithm $\log X$ are linearly dependent, that is answerable.

Comment: @whuber in a way. I need to apply the rank and order criteria to decide if the model is identified. To do that, I want to understand how many endogenous and exogenous variables there are in the model. Then I can see how many endog/exog variables are included/excluded in every equation. That way I can see if the model is non-identified, identified or over-identified. My problem is that I don't know if I can treat logs as distinct variables and assume that a log of an endog. is endogenous. If I have the answer, I can correctly count endog, exog and total variables.